# How can parse trees represent comments?

Tags: parsing, text-parsing

When parsing a programming language that contains comments, what are some techniques to incorporate those comments in the parse tree (concrete or abstract)?

One naive approach is to include comment productions in the grammar. But this would make it prohibitively large, because comments can appear anywhere in the token stream.

The other naive approach is to just filter comments out in the lexer or a preprocessing stage. However, there's legitimate reasons to want to access comments: syntax highlighting, automatic indentation, [programmatic access](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcomments), etc. For these tasks, it would be nice if comments could be handled uniformly with other syntactic elements.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Simple: attach them to AST nodes as auxiliary data. Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit does this; it is quite effective.